# How to show scanned QRCode user profile in my app in swift

Tags: swift, qr-code

First time i am working with QRCode

in our app i need to show the scanned user profile in my app when i scan that user QRCode in my app.. how to show scanned user profile in my app

i have written code for scan the user QRCode.. if i scan correct QRCode then here how to show  that person profile in my app

**code for scan the qrcode scanner:**

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation
class QRCodeViewController: UIViewController, AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate {
var video = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer()
let session = AVCaptureSession()

@IBOutlet weak var qrCode: UIImageView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    guard let captureDevice = AVCaptureDevice.default(for: AVMediaType.video) else { return }
    do{
        let input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureDevice)
        session.addInput(input)
    }catch{print("error")}
    let output = AVCaptureMetadataOutput()
    session.addOutput(output)
    
    output.setMetadataObjectsDelegate(self, queue:DispatchQueue.main)
    output.metadataObjectTypes = [AVMetadataObject.ObjectType.qr]
    
    video = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: session)
    video.frame = view.layer.bounds
    view.layer.addSublayer(video)
    self.view.bringSubviewToFront(qrCode)
    session.startRunning()
}

func metadataOutput(_ output: AVCaptureMetadataOutput, didOutput metadataObjects: [AVMetadataObject], from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {
    
    if metadataObjects != nil && metadataObjects.count != 0{
        
        if let object = metadataObjects[0] as? AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject{
            
            if object.type == AVMetadataObject.ObjectType.qr{
                let alert = UIAlertController(title: "QR Code", message: object.stringValue, preferredStyle: .alert)
                alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title:"Retake", style: .default, handler: nil))
                alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title:"Confirm", style: .default, handler: { (nil) in
                   // self.scannedCode = object.stringValue!
                    self.session.stopRunning()                    }))
                present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        }           
    }
    
    }
}
```

by using above code if i scan correct QRCode of user, then how to show that person profile in my screen.. please suggest me..

Comment: fetch that user profile and push the profile view controller or whatever you have to show it? what part are you having issues with?

Comment: What is 'the scanned user profile'?  What does your QRCode represent?

Comment: @Scriptable.. .. if i scan other user(means same app registred user) QRCode in my app then i need to show that person details like his name, contact details in my app.. how to do that.. how can i get that person details in my app

Comment: @ElTomato.. i am talking about same app registered user QRCode sanning.. one of the registred user scan other user QRCode the i need to show that person details in my app... how to do that

Comment: @Scriptable.. how to fetch Scanned user details and push to that viewcontroller

Comment: say if the URL from your QR code is myapp://profile/1234. make a request to your API for user with ID 1234